# VB6: Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library

Tags: reference, vb6, conflicting-libraries

Opening a VB6 Project, I get errors like:

> Errors during load. Refer to xyz.LOG

I open the log file and see these errors:

> Line 42: Class Threed.SSPanel of control XYZ was not a loaded control
>   class.

In this case I can see the problem is due to the Sheridan 3D Controls:   C:\WINDOWS\system32\THREED32.OCX

I thought the project was missing a component so, VB6 > Project > Components > tick the Sheridan 3D Controls and got this error:

> ---------------------- Microsoft Visual Basic ---------------------------
>   Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library
>   --------------------------- OK   Help    ---------------------------

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will give you the best way to get rid of this problem. I came across many ways, but this is the most best way to deal with..

Close the project. Right click on the vb project and open with notepad (not with vb). This Project file will only consist of all the references, libraries and information about forms and modules used in the project.

Now just remove the conflicting module or component file, you have problem, by just deleting the entire line.. Save and close it
and now open the project and add component. I swear you wont get that error.

Thank you. Enjoy

Comment: But without identifying the problem/conflicting component how do you know which one to remove from the project file?

Comment: You can identify the missing component when you open the forms of your project. The controls of missing component will be converted to picturebox and will give you an error..

Comment: Not if you've inherited the project and no longer know what they were, but yes I take your point.

Comment: It worked for me using windows 10, i has the same problem with mscomctl.ocx

Answer (score 3):

The way to troubleshoot this problem is to start a new VB6 project > Project Menu Components > tick the Components that are selected in the affected project until you get the error.

> ---------------------- Microsoft Visual Basic ---------------------------
>   Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library
>   --------------------------- OK   Help    ---------------------------

You need to narrow it down to the two OCX's that are conflicting.

In my case I narrowed it down to Sheridan 3D Controls / THREED32.OCX and Outrider Spin Control / SPIN32.ocx

To fix the problem I used RegSvr32 to unregister the OCXs - make sure you UNregister with the /u flag.

```
REGSVR32 "C:\WINDOWS\system32\THREED32.OCX" /u
```

I then copied the OCX's to the project folder and registered them again using:

```
REGSVR32 "C:\Dev\Project\THREED32.OCX"
```

Then in the project with the problem > Project Menu Components > select the item in the listbox Sheridan 3D controls / THREED32.ocx (you cant tick without getting the error or untick the conflicting one that is selected as its in use) > click Browse and reference it from the project folder rather than C:\WINDOWS\system32\

---

Another trick is close the project and unregister the affected ocx - make sure you UNregister it with the /u flag, eg

```
RegSvr32 "c:\Windows\system32\mscomctl.ocx" /u
```

Then open the project > Components > and you should see the "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)" is using a OCX file in C:...\Microsoft Vi..\VB98\mscomctl.ocx" rather than c:\Windows\system32\mscomctl.ocx.

The project should then load without these errors:

```
Errors during load. Refer to xyz.LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking the latest object library / reference from the references and check it again and then go for your desired reference (vb6 has few bugs which can be countered by a reverse process). I solved the error mentioned using this process.