# Name conflicts with existing module, project or object library

Tags: vb6

How do i install mscomm32.ocx on vb6?

I am trying to code for a serial port using a usb-rs232 and when I try to install mscomm32.ocx on the references of VB6 there is an error:

**Name conflicts with existing module, project or object library**

I cannot locate the file in conflict.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can either add it as a Component (so it appears in the tool box & can be hosted in a form) or add it as a Reference, but you can't do both & will get that error if you try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB6: Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835929/vb6-name-conflicts-with-existing-module-project-or-object-library)